# How to parse the String with custom tags?

Tags: android

Can anyone please tell me how to parse the below string?

`"Testing the parser - <tag><name>ANKIT</name><id>7</id></tag> <tag><name>VIKRAM</name><id>8</id></tag>. Some random text here"`

How can I get the name "ANKIT" which is inside the `<tag><name>` ?

I tried SAX parser.
I think the XML parsers works only when the starting line is `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Only ANKIT needed from the string? what about VIKRAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your text isn't valid XML but reminds more structure like HTML which isn't as strict, consider using HTML parser like https://jsoup.org/. With this library your code can look like

```
String myXML = "Testing the parser - <tag><name>ANKIT</name><id>7</id></tag> <tag><name>VIKRAM</name><id>8</id></tag>. Some random text here";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myXML, "", Parser.xmlParser());

String tag_name_text = doc.select("tag name")//CSS query to find <name> elements inside <tag> elements
                          .first()//take first result
                          .text();//get text it would generate in browser
System.out.println(tag_name_text);
```

Output: `ANKIT`

Comment: is it possible to remove these tags once the value is accessed?

Comment: @Aniruddha Probably yes, but that is subject of separate question. Also something tells me that this may be yet another case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Consider providing more details about what you are trying to do/accomplish, because if you for instance want to get rid of *all* tags in document and replace them with their text you can just call `String textFromDoc = doc.text();`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right, try

STRINGNAME.substring(STRINGNAME.lastIndexOf(""), STRINGNAME.indexOf(""));